# Ruby/Rails: Correct way to implement to_csv that considers active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Been out of the game for a while, getting back into it..

So, with that I have Companies.
Companies have_many Users and Users belongs_to a Company.

It's super easy to do `@company.users` to get the list of users.. awesome.

More over you can do handy things like `@company.users.where({foo}).limit({bar}).to_json` to get a json list of users etc... Works great.

I'd like to do `@company.users.to_csv` or better yet `@company.users.where({some query}).limit({somenumber}).to_csv` but of course it errors there and says "did you mean to_s" or something of that nature..

I swear we used to be able to do `.to_csv` or at least do this using Serializers but damned if I can remember how.. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I can add a custom method to the model for .to_csv but that doesn't work when you're getting a bunch.. Thoughts?  I feel like this should be trivial and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define to_csv function on user model like this.

```rb
   
  def self.to_csv(users, options = {})
    header_columns = [
      "Email",
      "First Name",
      "Last Name"
    ]

    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << header_columns
      users.each do |user|
        row = [
          user.email,
          user.first_name,
          user.last_name
        ]
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
```

And call it like this.

```rb
User.to_csv(@company.users)
```

Answer (score 0):

`require "csv"` dont forget to include the module

`@company.users.to_a.to_csv`

Comment: And whats the right way to specify what specifically from users I want to be outputted?  Like just their name and email or something..

Comment: @company.users.where(...).to_a.to_csv

Comment: or for example @company.users.(put your scope here that only selects your email and username).to_a.to_csv